# INFORMATICA post/pre SQL Query

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization, etl, sql-delete, informatica

I am using informatica and I am deleting a part from a table as a pre sql command .recently the table is getting bigger and the delete take too much time to be done i tried to split my query into small chunks and it works very fine on the database :

```
use [My_DB];
GO
DECLARE @BatchSize INT = 1000
WHILE 1 = 1
BEGIN
DELETE TOP (@BatchSize)
FROM [dbo].[My_Table] where condition=0 ;     
IF @@ROWCOUNT < @BatchSize BREAK
END
```

but when i tried it on INFORMATICA it doesnt work .
what can be the root cause or does informatica recognize this kind of command ?

Thank you .

Comment: 1. is the user you are using in DB and Infa are same? if no, then can you pls try using infa user? 2. can you create a stored procedure? And then call in pre/post SQL ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to partition the table, if possible. It would be possible to [truncate partition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/truncate-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), that takes almost no time at all.

Using a stored procedure as suggested by @Koushik would also be a good idea.

For any further assistance we'd need to know what is the nature of the issue. What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Do you get any error?